# Condition for a submanifold of complex Euclidean space to be analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry

I have seen, but don't fully understand, the following statement and sketch proof:

Statement: A codimension $2$ submanifold $C \subset \mathbb{C}^2$ such that $C$ has positive intersection index with every complex line is complex analytic (i.e. every tangent space is complex).

Sketch Proof:  Given a point $p \in C$ we can write $C$ as a graph over it's tangent space $T_pC$ in some neighbourhood of $p$. Now if the tangent space is not complex then one can "easily" find a complex line which has negative intersection index with $C$ at $p$. This is a contradiction and hence $T_pM$ is complex.

My problems are as follows:

1) What exactly is meant by the tangent space not being complex here?
2) How does one find this line precisely?

For the first point if we are considering $C$ as a subset in $\mathbb{C}^2$ then I guess we are talking about the tangent space as a plane in $\mathbb{C}^2$ which would necessarily be complex?

For the second point I guess that if we take a non-complex plane a complex plane both in $\mathbb{C}^2$ then their orientations will be oposite and hence the intersection index will be negative?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For $C$ a real submanifold of $B = \Bbb{C}^2$ then $T_pC$ is a real vector space and a subspace of the real vector space $T_p B$. Then $B$ has a complex structure making $T_p B$ a complex vector space. So the question is if $T_p C$ is a complex subspace of $T_pB$.

Comment: For starters, that submanifold needs to be oriented. A real 2-dim. subspace is complex iff it is $J$-invariant, where $J$ is the complex structure on $\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: @reuns Why take smooth charts at all? We’re in $\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: No, @reuns, as the OP framed the question it is only about working with the *tangent space* of $C$ as a subspace of $\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: So that the tangent spaces are complex isn't enough for the manifold to be complex (and to be an analytic variety), we also need the vanishing of the [Nijenhuis tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_complex_manifold)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @TedShifrin Yes the submanifold needs to be oriented and yes I only need to consider the question of whether the tangent space is $J$-invariant as a subspace.

Comment: @reuns You are right in that this is not enough in general and for my purposes it is fine to simply prove that C is an almost complex submanifold but since the standard almost complex structure on \C^2 is integrable the Nijenhuis tensor of the induced almost complex structure on C would necessarily vanish.

Comment: Ben, my point is that it's just a linear algebra question. Given an oriented basis $u,v$ for the tangent space of $C$, can you use the fact that this is not a complex subspace to write down $w$ so that $u,v,w,Jw$ has negative orientation? Try an explicit example or two.